# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to get the column id data from one table (user_info) and insert it in to another (user_profile). I'm really not sure what the error means, but you can see it in its entirety below along with the schema information for each table respectively.

There are lots of posts related to this question on SO, however i can't find anything that relates closely the my particular issue and haven't been able to apply a fix as suggested in the numerous threads.

Error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

user_info

```
CREATE TABLE `user_info` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`pass` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`joined` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=62 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

user_profile

```
CREATE TABLE `user_profile` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`f_key` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
KEY `f_key` (`f_key`),
CONSTRAINT `user_profile_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`f_key`) REFERENCES `user_info` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

The query, see third try block (included all that are related in case it helps

```
try {
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM user_info WHERE username = :user");
    $result->bindParam(':user', $username);
    $result->execute();
    $user_info = $result->fetch();
    $id = $user_info[0];
} 

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

try {
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT EXISTS( SELECT username FROM user_info WHERE username = :user)");
    $result->bindParam(':user', $get_username);
    $result->execute();
    $user_exists = $result->fetch();
    $exists = $user_exists[0];
} 

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

if (isset($_POST['submitProfile'])) {
    try {
        $result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_profile (user_id) VALUES (:id)");
        $result->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $result->execute();
    } 

    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the `insert`/`update` statement that is causing this error.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. Done.

Comment: user_profile has a foreign key 'f_key' which should contain an 'id' from user_info table. It's empty in your insert statement.

Comment: @subroutines perfect, that was the issue. Submit it as an answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user_profile has a foreign key 'f_key' which should contain an 'id' from user_info table. It's empty in your insert statement.